# Speed up tapply R code

Tags: r, performance, runtime, tapply

I have 100 matrices which each have 604800 columns, and 101 rows.
For each matrix, I need to reduce the number of columns to 60480 by computing the 10 column averages.

For example, for a vector

```
c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...)
```

The 5 column average would be:

```
c(3,8,13,18,...)
```

The code I am using to do this is:

```
col.av = tapply(col, rep(1:(length(col)/10), each = 10), mean)
```

Where `col` is one of my 101 x 604800 matrices. I have a `for` loop which iterates over the 100 matrices, however my problem is in the length of time needed to compute one run.

If I am just using one matrix, it takes 20 minutes+ to execute which is not feasible.
Are there any suggestions on how I can improve the speed of computation?

Thanks

Comment: See [rollmean](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/rollmean)

Comment: @zx8754 Not sure it applies here. OP wants `mean(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)`, then `mean(c6,c7,c8,c9,10)`.

Comment: Always show your code, it might just be that for loop is the answer but you've made an error.

Comment: `data.table(x=col, id=rep(1:(length(col)/10), each = 10))[,mean(x),id]` takes less than a sec for `col=sample(1:10, 604800*101, TRUE)`

Comment: @Khashaa But `col` is not a matrix, right?

Comment: Right. This corresponds the OP's use of `tapply`.

Comment: But OP says that `col` is a 101 x 604800 matrix.

Comment: To clarify, I originally used a 101 x 604800 matrix, then tried it with a 61084800 vector, but neither way is quick. The `tapply` code above is for use with the vector version

Comment: I will try out `rollmean` for my next stage, as I then need to calculate a rolling average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with `for` loop, this one works for your case:

```
col.av <- matrix(0, nrow(col), ncol(col)/10)
for (i in 1:ncol(col.av)) {
  col.av[,i] <- rowMeans(col[,(10*(i-1)+1):(10*i)])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without a for-loop and a custom function for readability. You can always wrap this in your for-loop or a call to apply.

```
#generate data
nc=604800 
nr=101
test_m <- matrix(rnorm(nc*nr),ncol=nc)

#function to get rowmeans by 'window'-columns
get_rowmeans <- function(mm, window=10){
  indices <- seq(1,ncol(mm),by=window)
  res <- sapply(indices, function(i){
    return(rowMeans(mm[,i:(i+(window-1))]))
  })
  res
}

tt <- get_rowmeans(test_m)
#check one
> all(tt[,1]==rowMeans(test_m[,1:10]))
[1] TRUE
```